# Confused in with real time web server choice

Tags: node.js, erlang, openfire, ejabberd

I want to develop real time web application like chatting & real time message conversion. I searched the internet and got confused with few technology

`erlang` `ejabberd` `nodejs` `openfire`

Right now im in java domain but won't hesitate to learn new things. So can anyone explain what is these technology in a very simple words and what technology i will need to achieve my target ? Does all these do the same thing ? and new technology suggestion from your side will be appriciated.

Comment: Reading the tag wikis should be a good start: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/erlang/info, http://stackoverflow.com/tags/openfire/info, http://stackoverflow.com/tags/ejabberd/info, http://stackoverflow.com/tags/node.js/info.

Comment: The type of responses this post is likely to elicit (at least from the Erlang community) are probably a better fit for the "Programmers" SE site than SO. To make it fit in anywhere better, though, it should probably be reworded a little -- some kid is bound to come along and view this as flame/proselytization bait.

Answer (score 1):

These are entirely different things :)

At the lowest level you have:

`Erlang/OTP` is piece of technology, that lets you built low latency, fault tolerant systems. It includes Erlang programming language, Erlang VM and OTP, which is set of patterns, libraries and good practices for writing those systems.

`nodejs` is a platform, that lets you code JavaScript on server side. It makes your life a little bit easier, when dealing with events, but Erlang is still better saving you from callback hell with actors and messages between them.

At the higher level you have xmpp:

`xmpp` is eXtensible Messaging and Presence Protocol. This is great for implementing chats like facebook chat, but because it is extensible, you can use it for any kind of messaging.

`ejabberd` is implementation of `xmpp` in `erlang`. There is also fork of `ejabberd` called [`MongooseIM`](https://github.com/esl/MongooseIM). Those will give you great start at developing your messaging application. They implement not only basic xmpp, but also couple of extensions (called `xep`s in xmpp community).

`openfire` is solution based on xmpp, so it is even higher level. For chatting and message conversion, this might be overkill, but it depends on your specific needs.

Comment: So from your points i think `Erlang` will be good to start as all are new for me. right ? So if want to develop a chat app like FB Gmail what technoly shall have to choose `Erlang` `ejabbered` both or just any one of these two ?

Comment: In my opinion: Erlang + MongooseIM.

Comment: is both free for commercial use ?

Comment: Yes, they are free for commercial use. In case, you run into obstacles, there is also support.

Comment: is `ejabbered` is `Erlang + MongooseIM` ?

Comment: No, MongooseIM is fork of ejabberd https://github.com/esl/MongooseIM It is slightly different, but they both run on Erlang.

Comment: yah both run on erlang but both are xmpp server

Answer (score 1):

Totally an opinion post:

- Erlang: Doing this from scratch with yaws and Erlang is the most straightforward way (its even a code sample in "Programming Erlang" 2nd ed.).
- Ejabberd is famously undocumented (and overkill for most webchat services), but it and its better documented/saner cousin (MongooseIM) are robust and already written.
- node.js is a cosmic joke played on monolingual ex-frontend web developers.
- I've never heard of openfire.

None of these things are bad to learn -- but that's because nothing is ever bad to learn (though some things aren't worth the time you would spend learning them).

The basic problem, I think, is that your goal is probably more broad than you realize, at least in terms of methods by which you can achieve the goal of "develop a web-based chat and communication service". There are a hundred web servers out there, each with its own way of doing active content service, each with a hundred more back-end plugins to a thousand more chat/conversation/comments/blather service frameworks. Any given "technology stack" will often involve a dozen languages throughout it (consider service pages written in PHP from an Apache server which proxies to a Tomcat webserver for pluggable content which calls out to a tiny scheme chat service which stores data in Postgres...).

The situation with most web stacks is, in my opinion, laughable. That is at the core of the Node.js idea, actually: pick a language most people know and stick with it throughout. The problem there is that not every language is well suited to every task (or any task...). But the basic idea that cutting the web tech clutter down is quite sound.

That said, I sincerely think the easiest place to get started is with a relatively tiny language with a small, hyper-knowledgable community around it, and focus on doing everything you can in that language. For this particular task (live web comms) I prefer Erlang and Yaws, writing the service from scratch until some element of it *obviously* is in need of some pre-written framework treatment. (That is not the right choice of tools for everything, though, so keep an open mind and learn to hate every language, at least a little -- they all suck, just some less than others.)